# Pascal style string in C and C style string compare in one function

Tags: c, string

I need to write a small function in C language, where I have one Pascal style string and another string, C style string. In this function I should compare those two strings and if both are same the function should return true, if not then return a false.

```
int main()
{
  char pascal_string // here I have a problem 
  char c_string[] = "Home";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67379/discussion-on-question-by-dexterr-pascal-style-string-in-c-and-c-style-string-co).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, something like this?

```
int compare(unsigned char *pascal, unsigned char *str, unsigned int strLength)
{
    unsigned int length = pascal[0];// get length of pascal string
    if(length != strLength)
        return 0; // if strings have different length no need to compare

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        if(pascal[1+i]!=str[i])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned char pascal[32] = {5, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
    unsigned char *ordinaryStr = "Hello";
    int t = compare(pascal, ordinaryStr, 5);// pass length of other string manually, e.g., 5
}
```

Comment: Hi giorgim, I need a function without a <string.h> library.

Comment: @Dexterr so... write one. `strlen` is the only function from string.h in this snippet, and its implementation is *trivial*.

Comment: Yes, but <string.h> is not allowed to use.

Comment: Thanks giorgim. How you will write a function if you have just one longer Pascal style string and split this string into two strings and that function return a two strings divided from this one string ?

Comment: @Dexterr: First create array of strings to hold those two separate strings. Start iterating the long Pascal string. You know how long the first string in the Pascal string is: check the first byte. Now copy as many bytes (from long pascal string) as in the first byte to first string array. When you are done, the next byte in the long pascal string will have length of *second* string, do the same with this case as you did in the first

Comment: Yes, I have forget to say, for instance first string should be till i comes and i = 4 but i<4 and up from 4 (including 4-th char) till end should be the second string, for instance.

Comment: @Dexterr: I gave you idea above, you should try to do it. Otherwise that is a separate question, maybe ask separately. But you will get  more help if you show what you tried first

Comment: @Dexterr:you can try to solve these issues yourself first. This one was not especially that hard too, you could have tried. You may learn more that way :).

Comment: Thanks giorgim I am doing it. If I have more questions I will feel free to ask ? ;)

Comment: @Dexterr: sure, just on SO it is preferred you show what you tried first. then you can ask new question on this site

Answer (score 3):

Simply walk down each array.  No need to pre-compute the length of the C string

```
int same_pstring_cstring(const char *p, const char *c) {
  unsigned char plength = (unsigned char) *p++;  // first `char` is the length
  while (plength > 0 && *c != '\0') {
    plength--;
    if (*p != *c) {
      return 0;
    }
    p++;
    c++;
  }
  // At this point, plength is 0 and/or *c is \0
  // If both, then code reached the end of both strings
  return (plength == 0) && (*c == '\0');
}

int main(void) {
  char pascal_string[1 + 4] = "\4" "Home";
  char c_string[] = "Home";
  char c_string2[] = "Home ";
  printf("%d\n", same_pstring_cstring(pascal_string, c_string));
  printf("%d\n", same_pstring_cstring(pascal_string, c_string2));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How you will write a function if you have just one longer Pascal style string and split this string into two strings and that function return a two strings divided from this one string ?

Comment: chux it makes me confused, why you dont write just char pascal_string[] = "\x4Home"; ?

Comment: @Dexterr If the pstring was the 4 `char` `"1234"`, then using `"\x41234"` is a problem as the `"\x"` escape sequence does not where to stop.  `"\x4" "1234"`

Comment: OK, @chux, how you will write two or more Pascal strings in one array ?

Comment: Could you explain this two lines: while (plen && *c) and return plen == *c; it is very interesting for me

Comment: @Dexterr `while (plen && *c) {` --> while `plen` is true (not 0) and `*c` is true (not zero)  { --> while p string still has characters and the not at the end of the c string {.    No need to perform a `strlen(cstring) or to pass in its length.

Comment: @Dexterr   `pascal_string3[1+4+1+5+1+4] = "\4" "Home" "\5" "Sweet" "\4" "Home";`  is 3 p strings in 1 array.

Comment: while(plen && *c) make a confusion, plen == 'H' && c == 'H', next step plen == 'H' && c == 'o' .... etc, so plen is always plen == 'H' , that makes me confused. plen is always true and is the same, and then you put p--; that make a confusion, could you please explain?

Comment: @chux:this code is a bit tricky from readability point of view :)

Comment: @Dexterr `plen` is the length of the pascal string.  It would start with the value of 4 not `H`.  It is not always 0 as each time and it decrements `plen--;` each time in the loop  becoming 3,2,1, and then 0.

Comment: @giorgim Revised with more explicit names/coding.

Comment: @chux, thanks a lot. One more question, this p++ makes me confused.This is pointer arithmetics ?

Comment: @Dexterr  Yes `p++` relates to pointer arithmetic.  It increments the pointer to the next object.  Since it is a pointer to `char`, the address increments by 1, the `sizeof char`.